# Simplifying $\frac{\tan(\alpha+\frac32\pi)-\cot(\alpha+\frac{13}2\pi)}{\cot(\alpha+\frac32\pi)+\tan(\alpha+\frac{13}2\pi)}$

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify $$\dfrac{\tan\left(\alpha+\dfrac{3}{2}\pi\right)-\cot\left(\alpha+\dfrac{13}{2}\pi\right)}{\cot\left(\alpha+\dfrac{3}{2}\pi\right)+\tan\left(\alpha+\dfrac{13}{2}\pi\right)}$$ We have $$\tan\left(\alpha+\dfrac{3}{2}\pi\right)=-\cot\alpha,\\\cot\left(\alpha+\dfrac{3}{2}\pi\right)=-\tan\alpha$$ What else?

Comment: Hint: What is the period of $\tan(x)$ and $\cot(x)$?

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer, $\pi$

Comment: What does that imply about $\tan(x + \pi n)$ and $\cot(x + \pi n)$ for integer $n$?

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer, well it's equal to $\tan x$. But we can't write $\alpha+\dfrac{13}{2}\pi$ in the form $\alpha+\pi n$ for integer $n$...

Comment: $\frac{13\pi}{2} = 5\pi + \frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer, I am not sure I see how that helps. We have $\tan(\alpha+5\pi+\dfrac{3\pi}{2})$.

Comment: $\tan\left(\alpha + \frac{3\pi}{2}\right) = \tan\left(\alpha + \frac{13\pi}{2}\right)$ and $\cot\left(\alpha + \frac{3\pi}{2}\right) = \cot\left(\alpha + \frac{13\pi}{2}\right)$

Comment: Defining $\beta:=\alpha-\pi/2$ might make this easier. But for full simplification, you'll also need to know how to simplify $\cos^2x\pm\sin^2x$. Do you?

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer, I arrived at $$\dfrac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{-\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}=-\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha}$$ In the authors' solution now they have multiplied by $$\dfrac{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}$$ to get $\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha=\cos2\alpha$. I don't see how they have simplified to $\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer, so their solution is wrong? I haven't studied sec.

Comment: @Hipo No, the solution is correct. If you notice, he/she has mentioned the substitution in the answer.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer, No I am talking about the solution suggested by the authors of the problem. See my previous comments.

Comment: @Hipo There's a well-known property that states $\tan^2(x) + 1 = \sec^2(x)$ where $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$. This can be proved easily by considering a right triangle.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer, My question is how $$-\dfrac{\left(\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha\right)\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{\left(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha\right)\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}$$ is equal to $$\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$$ which on the other hand is $\cos2\alpha$.

Comment: @Hipo $\sin^2(\alpha) + \cos^2(\alpha) = 1$

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer I guess that Hipo means why do they multiply by $\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}$ to make the further simplification. And to be honest, this simplification makes no sense to me since as you mentioned, the sum of squares simplifies to 1 already :p

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the period of both the tangent and cotangent functions is $\pi$ so in fact $\tan(x+13\pi/2)=\tan(x+3\pi/2)$ since $13\pi/2$ is a multiple of the initial shift value (you add $5\pi$, so 5 times the period, to be precise). Using your additional hints yield
$$\begin{align}\frac{\tan\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)-\cot\left(\alpha+\frac{13}{2}\pi\right)}{\cot\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)+\tan\left(\alpha+\frac{13}{2}\pi\right)}&=\frac{\tan\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)-\cot\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)}{\cot\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)+\tan\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)}\\
&=\frac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{-\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}\\
&=\frac{\cot\alpha-\tan\alpha}{\cot\alpha+\tan\alpha}\\
&=\frac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{\sec^2\alpha},\end{align}$$ where in the last line we use the fact that $\cot\alpha=1/\tan\alpha$. Now using the fact that $\sec^2x=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$ and that $\tan^2x=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$, we get $$\frac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{\sec^2\alpha}=\cos^2\alpha\left(1-\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}\right)=\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha,$$ the latter of which we can also write as $\cos(2\alpha)$ by using the formula $\cos^2x-\sin^2y=\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)$ in which $x$ and $y$ are both equal to $\alpha$. Hence, $$\frac{\tan\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)-\cot\left(\alpha+\frac{13}{2}\pi\right)}{\cot\left(\alpha+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)+\tan\left(\alpha+\frac{13}{2}\pi\right)}=\cos(2\alpha).$$